# Android Studio app link assistant digital asset links verification failed with nginx server with valid letsencrypt certificate

Tags: android, ssl, nginx, deep-linking, lets-encrypt

For my android app project , i wanted to use app deep linking, using app link assistant. Following steps I have done:

1. Added url intent filters.
2. Logic to handle intent
3. Associate website - created DAL file using debug certificate.
4. Save the file as assetlinks.json
5. Save the file under my server https://sub.subdomain.example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json
6. The file is accessible via browser.
7. But when tested inside the android studios app link assistant link and verify, it give error "The website hosting the Digital Asset Links file must support HTTPS with a valid certificate. Please ensure the DAL file is accessible at https://sub.sudomain.example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json".

I am using below configuration on server:

1. Ubuntu 16.04
2. PHP 7
3. SSL certificate generate via letsencrypt.org
4. fullchain.pem and key.pem used in SSL configuration
5. nginx/1.10.0
6. Android Studio 2.3

   **Can someone guide what could be possible issues? Why the android studio app assistant not verifying the file.**

Comment: got any solution? @Ramesh Dahiya

Comment: no I didnt get any solution to that, but I believe , the problem exists only with letsencrypt certificate I tested with godady SSL certificate and things were working fine.

Comment: I am using letsencrypt and I am able to verify on Android assistant. Is is still not working for you?

Comment: @Himanshu , its been while, I haven't tested that again, last time we get it over by using a paid godaddy certificate.

Comment: @RameshDahiya - Ok.